# Could not run Start Task on Azure Batch Service

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am trying to run Azure Batch with custom VM. Sometime I got the below mentioned error

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

If I retries booting VMs again it will work fine. It happens sometimes only.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate what your task do ?

Comment: I am installing some packages and mounting azure files on the VM

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that another process has locked the package database. The simplest method is to add retries around your start task code that is attempting to use the package database (`apt` or `dpkg`). If utilizing a custom image, you can look into [disabling automatic updates or periodic package list updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953779/programmatically-disable-apt-unattended-upgrades). Please understand the consequences of performing the latter.